# Изменение в ContextMenu при выделении нескольких строк в ListBox WPF

Tags: wpf

Есть `ListBox`. У него свой `ContextMenu`. Так вот как сделать так, что бы при выборе нескольких строк, делался доступным определённый пункт в меню?

Попробовал через `DepedenceProperty`:

```
public bool IsOneItemSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOneItemSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsOneItemSelectedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsMultiSelected.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOneItemSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOneItemSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow));



    /// <summary>
    /// Включение/выключение пунктов меню, в зависимоти от выбранных файлов
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ListBox_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOneItemSelected = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItems.Count > 1)? false : true;            
    }
```

в XAML (нужный пункт  - <kbd>Объединить выбранные файлы</kbd>):

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Planshets}" ContextMenuOpening="ListBox_ContextMenuOpening" SelectionMode="Extended">
                    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Добавить файлы" Click="btAdd_Planshets"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Удалить файлы" Click="MenuItem_Click_3"/>
                            <Separator/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Конвертировать ..."/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Объединить выбранные файлы" IsEnabled="{Binding IsOneItemSelected, ElementName=window}" />
                            <Separator/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Очистить список" Click="miClear_Planshets"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: А почему бы не было устанавливать IsOneItemSelected на SelectionChanged?

Comment: да все равно не работает... Все время пункт доступен, даже когда нет ничего в списке. Хотя IsOneItemSelected меняет свое значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал через Конвертер.

```
/// <summary>
/// Конвертер для включения доп. функций если выбрано бельше чем один элемент в списке
/// </summary>
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(bool))]
public class MultiSelectAddon : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((int)value > 1) ? true: false;            
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Merge" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, Converter={StaticResource MultiSelectAddon}, ElementName=listBox, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Для копки работает, для `ContextMenuItem` - **Нет.**

Вот еще один вариант [Получение выделенных строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582489/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-listbox%D0%B5-wpf-mvvm)

Comment: Хм, а оно так срабатывает? Является ли `Count` DependencyProperty? Вряд ли.

Comment: Прикинь... с `button` работает, а с `ContextMenu` нет

Comment: Хм. А если в ContextMenu просто написать `<MenuItem Header="Объединить выбранные файлы" IsEnabled="false" />`, так сработает?

Comment: просто `false` работает