# получить список выделенных строк в ListBox`е (WPF, MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть модель в которой есть список файлов. Этот список прибинден к `ListBox`.
Как получить список выбранных строк, если установлен режим `SelectionMode="Extended"`?

Comment: `SelectedItems="{Binding Selecteditems}"`?

Comment: так нету `SelectedItems` у `ListBox`, есть только `SelectedItem`...

Comment: Так вот же: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: но WPF не видит его/ Binding к нему не могу сделать, а его прибондить можно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не я первый столкнулся с этой проблемой.

Вот решение через CustomListBox: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868445/wpf-binding-selecteditems-in-mvvm

---

Создаем наследника от `ListBox` и добавляем DependencyProperty

```
public class CustomListBox: ListBox
{
    public CustomListBox()
    {
        this.SelectionChanged += CustomListBox_SelectionChanged;
    }

    private void CustomListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SelectedItemsList = this.SelectedItems;
    }


    public IList SelectedItemsList
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsListProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItemsList.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItemsList", typeof(IList), typeof(CustomListBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));


}
```

XAML:

```
<Windows ...
xmlns:customObjects ="clr-namespace:Preparation.CustomObjects"/>

<customObjects:CustomListBox x:Name="listBox" 
                         SelectionMode="Extended"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Planshets}"
                         SelectedItemsList="{Binding SelectedPlanshets, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private IList _selectedPlanshets = new ArrayList();
        public IList SelectedPlanshets
        {
            get { return _selectedPlanshets; }
            set
            {
                _selectedPlanshets = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPlanshets");
            }
        }
```

Теперь в нашей модели доступно свойство `ViewModel.SelectedPlanshet`